# What does it mean to push at a wide-open door?

Tags: meaning

To a certain extent, the warmth with which Meacham approaches Bush is merely a **push at a wide-open door.** History is usually kind to ex-presidents: even George Jnr, who left office with an approval rating of 32 per cent, is now attracting some friendlier attention. But few have seen their reputations improve like his father has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means to act as though there is a difficulty when no difficulty really exists. If a door is already open, you do not have to push it to go through it.